# Show complex numbers equal each other

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I have this math question:

> Let $z$ be a complex number and $a$ a complex number with $|a| = 1$. 
>    Show that:  $$|1 - a\overline{z}| = |a
>  - z|$$

So far I have this:

$$\mid 1-a\overline{z}\mid^2=\mid a-z \mid^2$$
Then I work with $\mid 1-a\overline{z}\mid^2$:

$$\mid 1-a\overline{z}\mid^2 = (1-a\overline{z})(1-\overline{a}z)$$
$$= 1-\overline{a}z-a\overline{z}+a\overline{z}\overline{a}z$$
$$1-\overline{a}z-a\overline{z}+\mid a\overline{z}\mid^2$$

I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $|a|=1\iff |a|^2=1\iff a\bar a=1$.

As you did, we have
$$|1-a\bar z|^2=(1-a\bar z)(1-\bar az)=1-\bar az-a\bar z+a\bar az\bar z$$
Now since $a\bar a=1$, we have
$$|1-a\bar z|^2=1-\bar az-a\bar z+z\bar z.$$

Now expand $$|a-z|^2=(a-z)(\bar a-\bar z)$$
and you'll get the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

In your last equation, replace $1$ by $a\bar a$ and use the fact that if $|a|=1$ then $|a\bar z|^2=z\bar z$